# Searching Sonos Music Library with SoCo in Python

Tags: python, sonos

I have another SoCo questions and I really hope someone can get me started.

I'm really pulling my hair out here. What am I doing wrong?

```
>>> from soco.music_library import MusicLibrary
>>> MusicLibrary.get_music_library_information('artists', search_term='Metallica') 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
TypeError: get_music_library_information() missing 1 required positional argument: 'search_type'
```

I copied the `get_music_library_information('artists', search_term='Metallica')` straight out of the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for having a go Bahrom. I got it to take action in the following way:

First i got the list of speakers with a

```
speakers=soco.discover()
```

and then I selected one of the speakers, calling it 'speaker'.

```
>>> for speaker in speakers:
...     if speaker.player_name == 'Office':
...             break
```

Then I appended the get command on to the speaker e.g.

```
>>> from soco.music_library import MusicLibrary
>>> speaker.get_music_library_information('genres')
```

and this works :)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but looking at [music_library.py](https://github.com/SoCo/SoCo/blob/master/soco/music_library.py) on github, I think you just need to instantiate `MusicLibrary` first:

```
>>> from soco.music_library import MusicLibrary
>>> MusicLibrary().get_music_library_information('artists', search_term='Metallica')
```

Comment: Thanks for having a go Bahrom. I got it to take action in the following way: